# Missing Website Logo for Non-WWW Link in Google Search Results

Tags: cloudflare, google-cloud-run, favicon, google-search, graphical-logo

My website, which is approximately two months old and has recently started ranking on Google Search. When users search for relevant keywords, the non-www version of my website appears in the search results, but there is no logo displayed. However, the website logo is visible with the www link.

Image: [non-www is displayed in the search but no logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axNHb.png)

I've attempted to access the favicon link from the non-www link, and I can confirm that the website icon is retrievable at this URL: https://diffcheck.net/favicon.ico
In my Cloudflare DNS settings, I have configured entries for both the non-www and root domains (@). Additionally, in Google Cloud Run, I have set up two domain mappings for both the non-www and www versions of my website.

Image: [domain mappings for non-www and www](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX3cW.png)

Image: [Cloudflare DNS, there are entries for non-www and root @](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JxRN.png)

I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue and ensuring that my website logo is displayed consistently across both the non-www and www versions of my site in Google Search results. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're facing an issue where the website logo isn't showing up for the non-www version on Google Search results, while it's fine for the www version. Here are some steps to tackle this:

Check Favicon Availability:
Ensure the favicon is reachable for the non-www version using the URL you shared: https://diffcheck.net/favicon.ico.

Verify Google Search Console:
Double-check that you've added and verified both the non-www and www versions on Google Search Console. Submit the sitemap for both.

Inspect Google's Knowledge Graph:
Confirm the correct logo and related info are linked with your website on Google's Knowledge Graph. Perform a search using "site:yourwebsite.com" to see if the logo appears.

Structured Data Check:
Validate that your website's markup has the right and consistent structured data (like schema.org) for both versions.

Validate Markup with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool:
Use Google's Structured Data Testing Tool to validate the structured data for both non-www and www versions. Make sure the logo is accurately specified.

Fetch as Google:
Utilize the "Fetch as Google" feature in Google Search Console to fetch and render the homepage for both non-www and www versions. Check if the logo fetches and renders correctly.

Request Indexing:
After ensuring the above steps are in place, request indexing for both versions in Google Search Console. This nudges Google to re-crawl and index your pages with the correct logo info.

Be Patient:
Remember that updating Google's search results and displaying the logo can take some time. Watch the outcomes over the upcoming few days.

If you've tried these solutions and the problem still exists, think about contacting Google support or hiring a web development specialist to make sure your website is set up properly.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive suggestions, I will get them a try!

Comment: @TaiTran No problem, if you need any help please ask me.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?